# Prove or disprove this inequality involving integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to **prove or disprove** this inequality:

For $f_1\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_2\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_1(x)|I_{\{x:f_1^2(x)\leq f_2^2(x)\}}dx\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}} I_{\{x:|f_1 (x)|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_2^2(x)dx\}}dx$$ where $I_E$ is the indicator function of a set $E$.

My attempt is to make the $$LHS  \leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_1(x)|dx=\int_0^\infty\mu\{x:|f_1|>t\}dt$$  but this seems no help cause what we need is $|f_1|$ less than a value of an integral. Could you give me some suggestions or hints to deal with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Show that the RHS is infinite unless $f_2=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thank you so much for your hints. I can show that if $f_2=0$, then LHS=RHS=$\mu\{f_1=0\}$. But if $f_2\neq 0$, Do you mean RHS must be $\infty$? Sorry, I am not very clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHS is the measure of $\{x: |f_1(x)| \leq c\}$ where $c=\|f_2\|_2^{2}$. Suppose this is finite and $c \neq 0$. Note that $\mu(\{x: |f_1(x)| > c\}\leq \frac  1 c \int |f_1(x)|dx<\infty$. Adding these we see that the real line has finite measure, a  contradction. Hence, either $c=0$, which ,means $f_2=0$ a.e. or RHS is $\infty$.

The inequality is trivial when $f_2=0$ a.e.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
May I ask for a further curious question that if the inequality is still true if the measure is a probability measure? That is if $\mu$ is a probability measure on X, do we still have
$$\int_{X}|f_1(x)|I_{\{x:f_1^2(x)\leq f_2^2(x)\}}d\mu(x)\leq\int_{X} I_{\{x:|f_1 (x)|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_2^2(x)dx\}}d\mu(x).$$ In this case, it seems that the contradiction argument is not working. I would appreciate it if you can give me an idea of this case. But anyway I'd like to thank you again for your answers to my posted question!

Comment: @user431550 It is not true. Take $\mu=\delta_0$  and$f_1=f_2=\frac 1 2$ for a counter-example.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much! @Kavi Rama Murthy